# how to pass Object to ORM Paginator Using Doctrine 2 and ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pagination, zend-framework2

i am unable to pass Doctrine Object to ORMPaginator function here is the snippet to my code

```
  Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as ORMPaginator;..............

if (count($SearchResults) > 0)
    {
        $ORMPaginator = new ORMPaginator($SearchResults);
    }
    else
    {
        $ORMPaginator = new ORMPaginator($VouchersRepo->createQueryBuilder('vouchers'));
    }

    $Adapter = new DoctrineAdapter($ORMPaginator);
    $Paginator = new Paginator($Adapter);
    $Paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(5);
    $page = (int) $this->params()->fromQuery('page', 1);
    $Paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
```

clearly $ORMPaginator = new ORMPaginator('pass me DQL'); requires Query to generate Paginator. Now how to pass Doctrine object(non DQL object) to ORMPaginator i cant get through this?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you need to use ORM paginator and Zend paginator both

```
use DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator as PageAdapter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as ORMPaginator;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator as ZendPaginator;
```

You should first initialize the query builder For example if category is your entity 
you can do it as follows

```
  $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('put your entity class here');
  $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('what ever entity you want'); 
  $queryBuilder->select('what ever your want');
  $q = $queryBuilder->getDql();
  $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery($q);    
  $paginator = new ZendPaginator(new PageAdapter(new ORMPaginator($query)));
```

I remember I learnt this technique from Some SO posting but I couldn't find it while posting this solution

Comment: i am already getting successful pagination and what you are doing is almost similar to what i am doing, what i want to know is that if there is a way to pass OBJECT (Doctrine) no DQL(Query) or pass  array(returned from FindALl()) to ORMPaginator Object

Comment: @noobie-php I am not sure I got your problem , Can you elaborate the statement "OBJECT (Doctrine) no DQL(Query) or pass array"

Comment: it means that ORMPaginator accepts only DQL Query, and i want to pass doctrine entity object or result that is fetched from FindAll() of doctrine